# Stale closure in custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a problem with stale closure and I don't know how to solve that.
Why data is undefined? I thought that `useCallback` watch deps and updates the value of data inside `getMember` function.

How should I write this function?

```js
export const useMembers = (): TReturn => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(getSpeakersGql);
  const members = data?.nodes || [];

  console.log(members) // after some time it has some elements
  

  // this function is triggered when data is defined 100%
  const getMember = useCallback(
    (id: string | undefined): Profile | undefined => {
      console.log('data', data); // logs undefined
      return members.find((member) => member.id === id);
    },
    [data, members]
  );

  return { getMember };
};
```

Comment: i know useRef can help with stale state

Comment: Probably the object instance of either `data` or `members` is not changing, even if the value in the object is changing.

Comment: You use optional chain `data?.nodes`, so the data could be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine with that hook and it works correctly.
The problem was with the function which was passed as a prop and then used in `useCallback`... With empty deps array...

```
<Select
  onChange={(value) => getMember(value)}
/>
```

and in the `Select` component:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        onChange(event.target.value);
    },
    [] // this caused a bug, should be [onChange]
  );
```

Comment: You saved me, thanks for the question and for the answer! I had a similar situation and I was also looking for the cause in the query hook... But it also turned out that there was a memo that was without the necessary dependencies.